# How to obtain scientific notation in R output

Tags: r, scientific-notation

This may be an old question but I am unable to get a solution.

I have the following sequence of numbers

```
  sequence1<-c(1,.5, .025,10,230,.006,.11)
```

Is there a way to convert these into scientific notation such that the output is

```
  "1"        "5*10^-2"  "1*10"       "2.3*10^2"    "6*10^-3"  "1.1*10-1".
```

I am unable to find a function but have looked all over

Comment: Is this what you need(gives a str repr)? `format(sequence1,scientific = T)`

Comment: No. This is the usual notation in r as an exponential one. I am looking for one similar to the notation in high school textbooks. 5326.6 is written as 5.3266 × 10^3. https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/standard-form.html .

Comment: Just `gsub` or use `english`